# TypeScript type narrowing on objecct properties?

Tags: typescript

This won't compile:

```
type QueryParamValue = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;

function encodeParam(x: QueryParamValue) {
    if (x === true) {
        return '1';
    }
    if (x === false) {
        return '0';
    }
    if (x === undefined || x === null) {
        return '';
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(x);
}

interface QueryParams {
    [_: string]: QueryParamValue|QueryParamValue[];
}

export function queryParams(params: QueryParams) {
    return Object.keys(params)
        .map(k => {
            if(params[k] === undefined) {
                return undefined;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(params[k])) {
                return params[k]
                    .map(val => `${encodeParam(k)}[]=${encodeParam(val)}`)
                    .join('&')
            }
            return `${encodeParam(k)}=${encodeParam(params[k])}`
        })
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join('&');
}
```

[codeplay](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiACgQ0WgtgNTQGwSgF4oBnYRASwDsBzKAHyhriwCMkmp2B7X-BDQ1urfPm5waAEwgAzWhGkBuAFCq5UgMbAqvERBpbes9JiwAKAB4AuWAmRnseQhACUUAN6qovqFTkoaxJiUkoED28-aKhECGA4RBEAcgBGZLVogF8fPwCgqxDSOQIydy9cmNj4xJSABgzKqBzo-ODQ0ilZBRolJmZCjpY4cUim6LiEpKhkxuymydqoQ2NZAFUAJQBJAGFeLDB9Q2BrNzUc1VpgJBKtaHgkVAxsMgrogG0AfTsKanoAXTsD0cz1wBAQjGBT3MLgQ73+53UECsh0QwCgmiMun0UAAjg5oS8LGBQWQgQSnFgyGMJjVpgB5dgAKwgOgAdABrCAgMjE0lucZ+NlYNBgCwckgAPjeVRiAT55jI7w5-yKUC68kU0hpst1i2mGp6Skyur8LVNvjaAEFEJgQGyqGQbXaFS9lf83DqLbSpiISYr3YLvUKRWKAG4EKVQAAGABJPCsTBBKeK3Fl4cR44nTKCLBH8GnowLg7q2UzeLQLMkAGTJYve80W-UiOMJoxJlMctOZturZO5-1ulWFoPNetVNkKfDXRAWABC-EEwnHMTLFZoVdrZ1UWSAA)

I figured out if I assign the prop to an intermediate value then it works fine:

```
export function queryParams(params: QueryParams) {
    return Object.keys(params)
        .map(k => {
            const value = params[k]; // <-- assign to intermediate value
            if(value === undefined) {
                return undefined;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                return value
                    .map(val => `${encodeParam(k)}[]=${encodeParam(val)}`)
                    .join('&')
            }
            return `${encodeParam(k)}=${encodeParam(value)}`
        })
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join('&');
}
```

But this behaviour seems unintuitive. Is there some way to make the first example compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need the variable:

TypeScript can not assume that `param[k]` will return the same value every time, because

- somebody might have changed the value in the mean time
- the property access might actually call a getter that randomly returns a different value

Comment: "somebody might have changed the value in the mean time" -- surely not in this exact scenario? All the code inbetween is synchronous and JS is singlethreaded. The getter is plausible, but is there no way to define on the interface `QueryParams` that these shalt not be getters? Or if they are, they are const?

Comment: TypeScript can not know that the methods you invoke leave `param[k]` unchanged. To do so, it would have to determine at compile time whether object references in different parts of the code actually refer to the same object. In addition, it would need to know which function implementation to check - which is particularly hard because prototypes can be modified at any time. You would need to extend the type system to describe, for each function type, the kinds of objects it modifies. This would need to conceptually partition the heap into mutable and immutable areas ...

Comment: ... but naming those is hard given that each execution of the same code may want a distinct mutation area. While [research into such type systems is ongoing](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/34572167.pdf), I know of no real world type system that has managed to tackle this problem successfully.